# Mysterious "Current" column in SharePoint Issues list

Tags: 2013, content-type, calculated-column, issue-tracking

I have a SharePoint 2013 list that is based on the Issue Tracking template. It has a "Current" column that is available in views, but is not displayed on the List Settings page. If I turn on manage Content Types, it's not visible under the base column "Issues" either. I assume it is a calculated column, but I can't find the column to see what the formula is. It returns "Yes" for every item in the list.

I created a new list and confirmed it is there as well. Since "Current" is such a common word, Google has nothing but noise for me. Any ideas on what this column is displaying or what it is useful for?

How to reproduce:

- From a SharePoint 2013 site, click Settings Icon|Add an App.
- From the Site Contents - Your Apps page, enter "Issue" in the "Find an app" text box and click Enter.
- Click "Issue Tracking" and create a new list.
- From your new list, modify the default view.
- Under Columns, you will see "Current". But not under List Settings.

Comment: Can you check if there is a workflow attached to list? If you attach the workflow it will automatically add the column with the name of the workflow which is a link to workflow history page (and if you delete the workflow the column remains in the list)..

Comment: I assume It happen on custom list creation as well. Do you have access to SharePoint server? If yes, got to 15 hive Features and search `Name="Current"` in all xml files. You will get a clue why SharePoint is adding this field automatically on list creation. It looks like a feature is doing this job.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Initially i thought you are talking about normal custom list. Then i realized you are talking about `Issue tracking List`.

Current Column is not visible anywhere as you mentioned but its internal name is

> IsCurrent

You can also modify the default value of this choice column by going in any column of the list and change the parameter `Field=IsCurrent` in url . This will allow you to edit the column default value but will not allow you to delete.

Having said all above, i still don't know what exactly this column does and where it comes from

Comment: Nope, I think this is a SharePoint 2013 thing. This was on the customer's site, I just tried on one of my third party hosted sites that definitely has no workflows or site columns, and I get the column. See my updated post for how to reproduce.

Comment: Also, if it was an actual column added by a workflow or Site Column, it should be visible under List Settings, or under the Content Type. It isn't.

Comment: see my updated answer